# Why is RPC connectivity broken for the Hyper-V Manager?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, rpc, windows, remote-access

I have a Hyper-V Server 2008R2 (Core) with numerous VMs running. This Hyper-V server is a member of a domain.

Since the server has nothing running on it apart from the Hyper-V service, the only way to make changes to my VMs is through the Hyper-V Manager remote MMC. I have the remote management MMC running on a **non-domain** workstation. (Note, it is not an option for us to add this workstation do the domain at this time.)

Since the workstation is **not** a member of the domain, I use the "workgroup" method of connecting to the Hyper-V service remotely:
- I created a local (non-domain) administrator user on the Hyper-V server.
- I created the exact same local administrator with the same password on the workstation.
- I completely disabled the firewall on the workstation, and enabled all remote management options on the Hyper-V server to ensure appropriate firewall rules are created.

Using this method, I was able to set up 8 seperate VMs and configure network connectivity without any problems.

However, after configuration of these VMs, it was determined that the Hyper-V server would need to be moved to a different local network to ensure proper functions (bad planning). It was decided that we should change the physical IP address of the physical network adapter to the new network, **before** changing the IPs of any of the virtual network adapters in any of the VMs. We moved the administration workstation to this new network as well, to ensure continued connectivity for remote management.

Once we had the server and workstation on the new network, we performed basic troubleshooting to confirm network connectivity between the workstation and server was still intact.
- ping: Success
- DNS resolution: Success
- NETBIOS: Success
- Terminal Services: Success (remotely connecting to the Hyper-V server)

Once this was confirmed, we fired up the Hyper-V Manager on the workstation to remotely connect to the server. The following error was received:
"Cannot connect to the RPC service on computer 'ServerXYZ'. Make sure your RPC service is running."

Usually, this error is attributed to authentication errors (whether workgroup or domain) or firewall issues. However, we already had the remote management MMC working successfully prior to the IP change, and we have made no changes to the users, passwords, or firewall rules.

Why would changing the IP cause this to break? What can we do to restore RPC connectivity from the Hyper-V 2008R2 (Core) OS?

Answer (score 1):

To connect using Hyper-V manager from a workgroup machine to an Hyper-v domain member server you also need  allow anonymous  DCOM remote access.

There is a tool from Microsoft that configues automatically all the necessary things for you: [Hyper-V Remote Management Configuration Utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/HVRemote).

If this not work i would recommend you to check the Windows Credential Manager of the client machine looking for bad entries. If you are not sure, delete all of them.

And finally, off course could be a really RPC error, the RPC error could be failing in your server. For be sure that it is not the issue connect to the server using MMC with other Snap-in as example *Local Users and Groups*.